# Vaadin: set up blank values to a float stepper

Tags: java, vaadin

I use vaadin float stepper to set up values. After I entered some value I want to clear the stepper but it returns the previous values (I mean using UI). However if don't enter anything it allows blank values. How can set up blank values back?

```
private FloatStepper weightFrom = new FloatStepper("Weight from");  
weightFrom.setWidth("100%");
weightFrom.setMinValue(0f);
weightFrom.setValue(null);
weightFrom.setImmediate(true);
privateLayout.addComponent(weightFrom)
```